# Controlling VBA Powerpoint autoevents from a checkbox on the PowerPoint ribbon

Tags: vba, checkbox, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint add-in with auto events which run when the presentation is saved or closed (e.g. updating footer, slide numbers). I would like these functions to be disabled through checkboxes on the ribbon. I've created the checkboxes in XML, but can't work out how to write the code to check their status and then run/not run my subs. I also want their status to be remembered when powerpoint is closed so next time it is opened, they are loaded correctly.

Any help would be appreciated, as I am getting very confused.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far, like the XML for the checkboxes. Also, try to ask one question at the time and describe the environment you are using in more detail. Powerpoint version?

Comment: You could store the status in CustomDocumentProperties or CustomXMLParts for the presentation.  Please post the code you are using (XML for the Ribbon, and VBA for the callback procedures).  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You ask several questions. You have to try to isolate the different parts into separate questions. That said, here's my suggestion:

1. When a checkbox is checked, set a global variable in the addin in a vba callback function.
2. The variable can be saved to the registry or a settings file right away or when PowerPoint closes.
3. When the auto events trigger, check the variable set in step 1.